# Cypress:Finding parent element

Tags: cypress

I got a tree of elements and each element got a toggle icon to expand it -My intention is to click on the toggle icon corresponding to the element have a text for ex "TIME PERIODS"
Currently i write my code like below , Is there a better way to do this?
Please see the screenshot for my element structure.

```
 cy.get('.tree-node',{ timeout: 60000 }).contains('TIME PERIODS',{force: true}).parent().parent().find('.tree-node-collapsed').click()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[each()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#DOM-Elements)** method is available in Cypress.io. Using which we can travell through tree of elements and can filter using text. Please follow below code approach:

**Code**

```
   cy
    .get('.tree-node')
    .each(($el, index, $list) => {
        // $el is a wrapped jQuery element
       $el.get('.tree-item').contains('TIME PERIODS').siblings('.tree-node- 
       collapsed').click();
     });
```

Comment: Thanks QaElite.I tried above code but getting an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed issues -working code given below

```
cy.get('.tree-node').each(($el, index, $list) => {
    // $el is a wrapped jQuery element
     cy.wrap($el).get('.tree-item').contains('TIME PERIODS').parent().siblings('.tree-node-collapsed').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do like shown below also with out using .each

```
cy.get('.tree-node').get('.tree-item').contains('Header').parent().siblings('.tree-node-collapsed').click();
```